# Simple *nix tool for listening to HTTP requests and logging the request data

Tags: linux, macos, http, unix

What's a simple, easy-to-use *nix tool that will listen to requests on a given port and log the request header and body?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about netcat?

```
sudo nc -l 80
```

**Update**: Here's what I see when I send a request through a browser.

```
[~]$ sudo nc -l 80
Password:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Is there a verbose option to show request details such as all the request headers (including request method) and the the body. Right now it looks like it is just outputting the body.

Comment: It should just print every byte received on that port. Can you check again? See updated answer for what I see.

Comment: in my case I had to run the command as `sudo nc -l -p 80` for it to work